# Finding an element in multi dimensional array in C Programming

Tags: c, arrays

I was having some problem when trying to loop thru multi-dimensional array in C programming. The expected output should be in this way:

```
Enter no. of names: 4
Enter 4 names: Peter Paul John Mary
Enter target name: John
Yes - matched at index location: 2

Enter no. of names: 5
Enter 5 names: Peter Paul John Mary Vincent
Enter target name: Jane
No – no such name: -1
```

And here is my code:

```
int main()
{
char nameptr[SIZE][80];
char t[40];
int i, result, size;

printf("Enter no. of names: ");
scanf("%d", &size);
printf("Enter %d names: ", size);
for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    scanf("%s", nameptr[i]);
getc(stdin);
printf("\nEnter target name: ");
gets(t);
result = findTarget(t, nameptr, size);
if (result != -1)
    printf("Yes - matched at index location: %d\n", result);
else
    printf("No - no such name: -1\n");
return 0;
}

int findTarget(char *target, char nameptr[SIZE][80], int size)
{
    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < 80; col++) {
            if (nameptr[row][col] == target) {
                return col;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

However, when I entered "Peter Paul John Mary" and trying to search , it does not return me with the "Yes - matched at index location: 2". Instead, it returned me with the No – no such name: -1. So I was thinking which part of my code went wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**Modified portion**

```
int findTarget(char *target, char nameptr[SIZE][80], int size)
{
int row, col;
for (row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        if (strcmp(nameptr[row]+col, target)) {
            return row;
            break;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use `nameptr[row][col] == target`, you want to replace it with `strcmp(nameptr[row][col],target) == 0`. `==` compares the pointers (memory addresses), `strcmp` compares the actual values of the strings, and returns `0` when they match.

Comment: After I changed it to string compare, when I trying to perform a search, the cmd just stopped working and it has no error message at the output there. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, just took another look at your code. `nameptr[row][col]` isn't a string; its a single character. Try `nameptr[row]+col`

Comment: Okay but now the problem is the returned index location isn't correct. Also, if I tried to find a name which is not in the array, it still returning me with the Yes, any ideas? Can you help me check with the modified portion?

Comment: When you entered the names, did you hit enter after each one, or did you put them all on one line? If the first, then get rid of `col` entirely; each name will be in its own row, so take out `col` and its loop, just return `row`. If the second, then its much more complicated.

Comment: Yes, I put all of them in one line. Yeah, I took out already but it still won't work.

Comment: Sorry but I get a little bit confused. Do you mind to move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88852/discussion-between-fsq-and-denise).